# removeClass doesn't stop transition in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to stop transition animation, to do that I just remove "animation" css class that defines the transition for element. It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Why's so?

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.animated {
  transition: width 5s, height 5s;
}

.big {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**HTML (needs jQuery):**

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').addClass('big animated')">start</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').removeClass('animated')">stop</a>
<div></div>
```

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQPJmo

Comment: Check my Updated answer if that what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

add a `.notransition` class instead of removing the `.animated` class:

css:

```
.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').addClass('notransition')">stop</a>
```

Example (works in Firefox):
https://jsfiddle.net/v149sht6/4/

Comment: ok but why we should set it to none ? why removing is not working ? a bug or a feature ?

Comment: @Temani I don't know if it is a bug, I guess firefox just manages transitions differently. But the only solution (that i've found) is the set the trantition to `none`

Comment: Thanks JiiB your solution works, it's also interesting to know why it's different for Firefox.